# ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES caused by my script

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code that causes "ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES" in my Chrome browser.

I thought about to replace the setInterval() function with setTimeout().
Do you think it would be a better idea to use setTimeout ?

Or do you have an idea how to improve my script ?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/UpdateDBentries",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#updTotalDBentries").html(response.result);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    //alert("Failure: [Index] - UpdateDBentries: " + response.responseText);
                },
                undefined: function (response) {
                    //alert("Undefined: [Index] - UpdateDBentries: " + response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    //alert("Error: [Index] - UpdateDBentries: " + response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

```
// Working
        public JsonResult UpdateDBentries()
        {
            // This way is much faster then using "Count()"
            int? DbEntriesResult = entities.Measurement.Max(u => (int?)u.id);

            return Json(new { result = DbEntriesResult }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I expect no ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES.

Comment: i suggest you use sse or websockets if you want long pooling

Comment: I am accessing to a MSSQL database in the background. So the UpdateDBentries is calling this function. Added my code above.